# How to add a post build event to llvm using cmake

Tags: cmake, llvm, clang, post-build-event

I want to add a post build event to llvm's clang using cmake, but i just can't figure out where. The event should occur after every build of clang, without considering changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need [add_custom_command()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_command) function with `TARGET` signature and `POST_BUILD` keyword.

e.g.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
  COMMAND scp mytarget foo@bar
)
```

Comment: ok, but where should the add_custom_command() function be placed ?

Comment: Somewhere in one of `CMakeLists.txt`s. For example, right after target declaration for which you wish to add post-build step.